# UIWebView в swift "замораживает" страницу

Tags: javascript, swift

Есть UIWebView, который отлично прогружает из локального хранилища html с css-стилями и javascript-ом.

Но при прокрутке UIWebView анимашки "замерзают", и включаются только после окончания скролла.

Как это исправить?

Comment: и проблемы нет, если грузить все ресурсы из интернетов, только локальные приводят к такому багу?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нет. Если удаленно грузить страницу - та же проблема. к примеру:  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://appic.pro/l4/index.html")!)
        print(request)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

Comment: просто показалось странным, что вы заостряете внимание на том, что локальные страницы

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я просто описал ситуацию. Там немного все сложнее. Там с рестапи приходит ссылка на зип архив. он качается, распаковывается и отображается.

Comment: действительно есть такая проблема. Пишут, что и в старом Safari такая была. попробовал использовать WKWebView - вроде работает. попробуйте, если получится перенесу в ответ.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я уже пробовал, удаленно работает отлично,но в iOS8 он плохо дружит с локальными ресурсами. Если делать через loadRequest - он вообще не отображает. Советуют использовать loadHTMLString. В этом случае грузит, но не подтягивает css и javascript. Как вариант, думаю поднимать локальный WebServer - но это костыль.

Comment: не берусь сказать за css, но js должен грузиться нормально

Comment: а можно посмотреть что именно у вас в loadHTMLString?

Comment: Для WKWebView воспользовался следующим решением : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28676439/4995378  Работает хорошо.